# How to attach an image to another in Corona?

Tags: coronasdk

I'd like to attach an image to the side of another image so that when one of them is moved or a change happens to it (mostly moved) the other image will remain in the side of the first image.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this:

Just make an image sheet:

```
-- first, create the image sheet object
local options =
{
    -- The params below are required

    width = 70,
    height = 41,
    numFrames = 2,

    -- The params below are optional (used for dynamic image sheet selection)

    sheetContentWidth = 70,  -- width of original 1x size of entire sheet
    sheetContentHeight = 82  -- height of original 1x size of entire sheet
}

local imageSheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "fishies.png", options )

local myImage = display.newImage( imageSheet, 1 )
```

If you have many of these you can make a display group:

```
local myImage = display.newImage( "image.png" )
local myImage2 = display.newImage( "image2.png" )

local group = display.newGroup()
group:insert( myImage )
group:insert( myImage2 )
```

A simple way is also simply whatever makes the first image move, code it so it moves the second image as well:

```
image1.x = 567
image2.x = 567+offset
```

Comment: You didn't get my question. I'm trying to get both images sided to each other. So for example if I add physics to both images they both would fall down lined side to side. If I apply force to them they would fly away in the same form they looked like in the static position.

Comment: then just put them in a display group and whatever you do to the group will happen to all objects in that group.